# azure function complexity level guidance

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, azure-functions, dto, code-complexity

I am trying to convert an existing API app that uses MVC model and Entity framework into an Azure function. This is to take advantage of the serverless architecture in Azure function for its scalability and cost model.

The current API app is not very time consuming - basically it accepts some message in JSON format, converts it into C# classes, does some amount of transformation and then saves into the database using Entity Framework. Requests can be completed within 10 seconds hence I see this fitting into Azure Function time limit for Consumption Plan.

The thing that worries me is the amount of code that sits in the app as it is a layered architecture having DTOs, Models and data access layer (a true layered architecture). Would Azure function be a good fit for hosting such an application with layered architecture?

I feel Azure Function should be ideally a small piece of logic. I wanted to check if there could be any issues in this approach. I was also reading that keeping a lot of files and dependencies in a function can increase initial load time for new instances.

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Also if Azure Function is not the right approach for such complex codes what could be alternatives - should I continue to maintain this as an API app with the current scalability and pricing constraints coming with app services?

I believe web jobs would also have similar constraints as the Azure Functions and MS is now asking everyone to move to Azure Functions.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Functions can handle full code scenarios. My suggestion would be to definitely use the Visual Studio tooling support and precompile. That will also give you the full goodness of the IDE and facilitate unit tests and other best practices. 
Here's a link and tutorial to the VS tooling for Azure Functions for further reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/05/10/azure-function-tools-for-visual-studio-2017/

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually I have already gone through this link and others on this topic. The thing I see is mostly the examples consist of showing a simple run method. Would you be aware of a any example of implementation for a more complete application scenario probably on GitHub? Appreciate again for taking time to help in this regard.

Comment: Thank you so much. this is really very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Basically I have done the same. I created class libraries that implement the processing of the call's input parameter. Then I just reference the class libs and call into these libs from the Azure Function. Basically I just defer executing of the task to the class libs. The benefit of this is two-fold:

- Reduces complexity of the Function code to just a try-except, instantiate the handler and invoke the handler with the Function params
- Being able to (automated) test outside of the Azure environment